# SQL access joins (inner and left probably?)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables and they are:

```
---------ATRIB---------
ITEMID NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE VALUE
100001 Length              5
100001 Height              6

-------TECHDATA--------
ITEMID NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE VALUE
100001 Length              
100001 Height
100001 Weight
```

The situation:
The user creates a table ATRIB and wants to update table TECHDATA with according values, however he only has the values of length and height although he needs to enter all values in the TECHDATA table.

I want to check if all the values that are present in TECHdata are present in ATRIB table. I've tried this:

```
select ITEMID,NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE,VALUE
from       atrib    a
inner join TECHDATA b on a.itemid = b.itemid
left  join TECHDATA c on a.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE = c.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE
```

But this gives a syntax error, also tried a left join but still could not get the results I've wanted, maybe you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us **what** syntax error you are getting... or where ;)

Comment: I see 2 mistakes. Table alias not being used correctly and a lack of parenthesis for nested joins.

Comment: I get  Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression a.itemid =b.itemid left join TECHDATA c on a.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE = c.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an ambiguous column name. An ambiguous column name happens when there is a column with the same name in different tables. In this case, between the `Techdata` and `Attrib` columns.

This query assumes you don't mind the duplicates.

```
SELECT a.ITEMID,a.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE,a.VALUE
FROM ((atrib AS a
INNER JOIN TECHDATA AS b on a.itemid = b.itemid)
LEFT JOIN TECHDATA AS c on a.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE = c.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: I get the same error Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression a.itemid =b.itemid left join TECHDATA c on a.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE = c.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE

Comment: @user2893780 I made minor changes (because I hadn't realized you were in MS-Access SQL)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to qualify from what WAS provided to what is STILL NEEDED.  This can be resolved by doing a LEFT-JOIN and getting the records that are still missing to notify the user back with.  Start with ALL DATA REQUIRED for the given ItemID, then compare to ATRIB

```
select
      td.NameOfTheAttribute
   from
      techdata td
         LEFT JOIN Atrib a
            on td.itemID = a.itemID
   where
          td.itemID = 1000001
      AND a.itemid IS NULL
```

You KNOW the ID the person is trying to look for, so put that ID specifically in the where clause.  Then, by including the AND ... IS NULL into the WHERE, it will only return those tech data records that DO NOT have a value provided for being populated.  Then you can show the user based on the NameOfTheAttribute that was returned.  If no records are returned, then all pieces have been filled in and you can continue with the actual SQL-Update process.

If the attribute table created by the user can have multiple itemIDs, then I would revise the query slightly to accommodate.